# How do I change the spacing between the header of a UICollectionView and the rest of the cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewController.  It has a header, and then it has a bunch of cells.  The spacing from cell to cell is fine.  But I want to eliminate the spacing from the header to the first cell.  How do I do this?

EDIT: I was able to adjust it using the attributes inspector in the Storyboard.  Turns out that I had accidentally made it bigger than the image inside of it, which caused the *appearance* of there being too much space.

Comment: how you figured this issue...

Answer (score 4):

use the property sectionInset of UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

Here is an example code:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 60,60);
```

This will help you out to set your collection from top,bottom,left,right.

**EDIT:**

```
UICollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Comment: UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Yes, but where do I assign my new "layout" variable?.. 

like, self.layout = layout; ?

Comment: But I only want to set this for my header.

Comment: Change only the top part, where I have set 0 , keep others to 0

Comment: I added this:

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];

But that makes my header disappear.  I just want the spacing between the header and the first cell to disappear.

Comment: Try this UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,0,0,0), I can't tell you the exact parameters for UIEdgeInsetsMake without having a look at your collectionview on screen and your code

Comment: You can only fix it by change value for top in UIEdgeInsetsMake

Comment: Even if I only adjust the top value, the header still disappears.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet along with the Image how do you want to make it look like